# Convert accountExpires to DateTime in powershell commandline (last step, help needed)

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have the following piece of code that works fine to output the user's displayname and the accountExpires attribute from AD. I am running them on commandline because of restricted mode at work:

```
$objSearch.findall() | %{" " + $_.properties.displayname + "| " + $_.properties.accountexpires}
```

Now I need to convert this output, specifically the accountExpires attribute to a humanly readable date.
After googling I figured that I can use something like the below to convert between the accountExpires and a datetime.

```
[datetime]::fromfiletime(129138320987173880)
```

But I am having issues combining the two. I tried the following:

```
$objSearch.findall() | %{" "+ $_.properties.displayname + " " + [datetime]::fromfiletime($_.properties.accountexpires)}
```

Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection", for "FromFileTime" to type "System.Int64": "Cannot convert the "System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection" value of type "System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection" to type "System.Int64"."
At line:1 char:96
+ $objSearch.findall() | %{" "+ $*.properties.displayname + " " + [datetime]::fromfiletime <<<< ($*.properties.accountexpires)}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

```
$objSearch.findall() | %{" "+ $_.properties.displayname + " " + [datetime]::fromfiletime $_.properties.accountexpires}
```

Unexpected token '*' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:99
+ $objSearch.findall() | %{"This is "+ $*.properties.displayname + " " + [datetime]::fromfiletime $_ <<<< .properties.accountexpires}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (_:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

How can I convert the accountExpires to a humanly readable date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just miss that the underlying ADSI COM object presents properties as arrays here is a way to get the `accountexpires` property, just use `$_.properties.accountexpires[0]`.

```
$search = [ADSISearcher]"OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr"
$search.Filter = "(cn=Jean Paul Blanc)"
$user = $search.FindOne()
$user | %{" "+ $_.properties.displayname + " " + [datetime]::fromfiletime($_.properties.accountexpires[0])}
```

This give for me :

```
 Jean Paul Blanc 12/07/2012 00:00:00
```

Comment: But I also wanted milliseconds :( I think there is an `O` "round-trip" format that does it.